# "There is no" vs. "There is not"

Tags: definite-article, negation, determiners, existentials

> There is **no month** in calendar **that does not have** a festival.
>   There is **not a month** in calendar **when there is not** a festival.

Do the two sentences mentioned above mean the same thing?
Why or why not?

Comment: Note that *month in calendar* is not idiomatic. It's completely unnecessary to include ***calendar*** anyway, since there definitely aren't any "months" that *aren't* in ***the*** calendar, but if you *are* going to include it you need the definite article.

Comment: FumbleFingers, it may be necessary if you want to emphasis the whole year, ie the whole calendar, as "There is no month that does not have a festival." could mean say just the summer months or winter etc.

Comment: @rkchl, I think the opposite is true. If you say "there is no month...", it is implied that you are talking about all the months in the year. If you mean in the summer, I'd expect you to do that. Not that there aren't reasons to use "in the calendar" (although I would prefer "in the year"), but I don't think that is one of them

Comment: @rkchl: By default, any assertion of the general form *There is no X that [has property Y]* strongly implies *no month **at all***. For it to reference a subset of all possible months the surrounding text would need to *explicitly* specify which months are included or excluded. And OP has supplied no such limiting context, so unquestionably the default ***all*** interpretation must apply.

Comment: These 'negation' questions make me nervous - especially the second one, which I more often hear phrased as  "There is not a month in the calendar where there is not a festival".  But yes, they mean the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, they do have the same *meaning* but they do not have the same **tone**.

What I say with tone is that when we talk we don't just spit words through our mouths, we express emotions, we change the tune of our voices.

And it reflects also in language.

To explain this, I will give you an example:

> I wish you stopped hitting me.

That is pretty nice isn't it? I am only mildly irritated with your hitting, and I wish you stopped it. Now, let's have a look:

> I wish you would stop hitting me!

Wow, beside the exclamation mark, we have a much more strong and concise writing. This means I am irritated, as the previous sentence, but now I'm nervous. The construction *wish* + *would* gives us this clearly annoyed view.

For your sentences I believe this is the case. The first sentence is more like an information about the year and its festivals. But the second one is almost an outflow of frustration, like "Ow heck, I only see festivals in this freaking calendar! What's the problem with these people?"

Comment: *Not a month* implies that you checked every month or are familiar with every month for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

They mean the same thing; both not and no indicate negation.

However, the use of no indicates stronger negation.